# react-native-reanimated fails entire react native project build

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-reanimated

I am currently facing an issue where whenever I try to build my react-native project with react-native-reanimated installed the project fails to compile. When I uninstall react-native-reanimated¨the entire project builds and runs successfully.

I have tried to reset the cache by running

```
npm run start --clear-cache
```

And

```
npx react-native run-android
```

The version installed is:

```
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
```

This is the output that I receive whenever I try to run the project with the package installed. I suspect that there is a mismatch between the package version and gradle. However 3.3.0 is the latest release of the package.

```
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Android gradle plugin: 7.4.1
Gradle: 7.5.1
...

  -- Build files have been written to: C:/Work/repositories/react-native-client/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/Debug/181x6l2t/arm64-v8a

  C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
        -C ^
        "C:\\Work\\repositories\\react-native-client\\node_modules\\react-native-reanimated\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\181x6l2t\\arm64-v8a" ^
        reanimated
    from C:\Work\repositories\react-native-client\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android
  ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s

    at makeError (....\react-native-client\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at ....\react-native-client\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (....\react-native-client\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (....\react-native-client\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Whenever I try to run the ./gradlew clean script in the android folder I also receive an *No such file or directory* error. I also suspect that it has something to do with the permissions or the react-native-reanimated based on other similar issues from other users.

```
./gradlew clean
:ReactNative:Running '[node, -e, try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e) {console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);}]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/mnt/c/repositories/Pension/react-native-client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 397

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot run program "node" (in directory "/mnt/c/repositories/Pension/react-native-client/android"): error=2, No such file or directory

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

How can I solve this issue?

UPDATE:
Seems like there is an open issue on their Github repository. Which probably means this is a bug from their side.

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/4726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sound absurd, but what worked for me is reducing the project's path length!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line  in your babel.config.js

```
   module.exports = { ...,   plugins:
 ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
 
 };
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Can you clarify how babel is the cause of the issue? Because I can't see the relation between Babel and the error that I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Reanimated v3.x.x require `React-native` 0.7x.x, trying to upgrade yoru react native version

Answer (score 0):

add following code in your babel.config.js file

```
 plugins:[
    ...
    [
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin', {
            relativeSourceLocation: true,
        },
    ]
],
```

maybe it's because Reanimated plugin generate source location using absolute path, so that's why the file is not accessible using absolute path by adding above code it will user relative path and hope it will work.